# Huion 420 tablet + ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

I need help making my huion 420 tablet work with my ubuntu 14.04 64-bit computer, websites or instructional videos would be very helpful and thank you

Answer (score 0):

This link detailing the H610 setup can be used to setup the H420 as well: [HUION H610 Tablet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500141/huion-h610-tablet)

I would use the latest source code, and not any of the releases v5, v6, etc.

For a script to control the buttons you can pull what you like from the following post: [Limit a graphics tablet to one monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839161/limit-a-graphics-tablet-to-one-monitor/)