# How set wacom display to single screen when using dualscreen on ubuntu22.04

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, wacom, graphics-tablet

I use a wacom intuos 3 graphic tablet. I am using two screens. I would like to limit it to one screen. I found this tutorial: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafiktabletts/#Dualscreen

While the command `xsetwacom` exists on my machine, I can't find the configuration file to make the necessary changes.

Comment: I found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/839161/limit-a-graphics-tablet-to-one-monitor I did not try, though.