# Installing Huion tablet

Tags: software-installation, graphics-tablet

I'm not sure how to install my Huion H610 Pro tablet. It's completely unresponsive when I plug it in. I've found things on using the DIGImend software, but the installation and setup directions are less than clear. I don't understand what I'm doing in the least, and I'm finding no guides that are comprehensible for someone new to Ubuntu.

I use Ubuntu GNOME specifically.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500141/huion-h610-tablet). It has the same solution, but the issue is different so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I've done what I can to simplify and decipher the instructions for you:

> **[Installing](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers#installing)**
>
> Kernel v3.5 or newer is required.

This means you will need at least Ubuntu 14.04 or 12.04.5 ([source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support)). If you're not sure, run `uname -r`, which prints the kernel version.

> Kernel headers or the build tree for the running kernel are required.

From what I can tell, kernel headers are installed automatically. (I ran `dpkg -l linux-headers*` to see what was installed on my system.)

> **Installing Debian package**
>
> If you're using Debian or a derived distro, such as Ubuntu, please try using the experimental .deb package. If it works for you, this will remove the need to reinstall the driver after each kernel upgrade. If it doesn't work, please report the issue.

The .deb package is available [here](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/releases/download/v6/digimend-dkms_6_all.deb) (from the [releases page](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/releases)). Try running it to do the installation. (Ubuntu is based on Debian. DEB files are Debian installers, similar to EXE files on Windows or DMG files on Mac.)