# Huion 580 tablet with ubuntu 16.04 - USB detected but doesn't work or appear in xinput

Tags: drivers, usb, tablet, input-devices, graphics-tablet

I'm attempting to use a Huion 580 tablet on a Lenovo T460p running 16.04 with kernel version 4.4.0-36-generic, but the device is completely unrecognized (functionality-wise, at least) by the machine.

I have confirmed that the hardware is in good shape: I've successfully used the tablet on a windows machine, and all the hardware indicators on the device itself (hovering the pen over the tablet surface makes lights come on, etc.) operate as expected.

The output of `lsusb` is as follows:

```
lhallock@selene:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b541 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 256c:006e  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The unlabeled `256c:006e` is the tablet, as confirmed by

```
lhallock@selene:~$ sudo uclogic-probe 1 2 | uclogic-decode
[sudo] password for lhallock: 
  Manufacturer: HUION???
       Product: PenTablet?
         Max X: 32000
         Max Y: 20000
  Max pressure: 2047
    Resolution: 4000
Internal model: H580
Buttons status: HK On
```

However, the device doesn't appear in `xinput list`:

```
lhallock@selene:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I've also tried installing the `digimend-dkms_6_all.deb` package, which claimed to install correctly via GUI but didn't change any of the above output. I have also tried installing the drivers manually from [here](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers), but ran into this problem:

```
lhallock@selene:~/Downloads/installation/digimend-kernel-drivers-master$ sudo make install 
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/lhallock/Downloads/installation/digimend-kernel-drivers-master modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic'
  INSTALL /home/lhallock/Downloads/installation/digimend-kernel-drivers-master/hid-kye.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/lhallock/Downloads/installation/digimend-kernel-drivers-master/hid-polostar.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  INSTALL /home/lhallock/Downloads/installation/digimend-kernel-drivers-master/hid-uclogic.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  DEPMOD  4.4.0-36-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic'
install -D -m 0644 digimend.conf /etc/depmod.d/digimend.conf
depmod -a
install hid-rebind /sbin/hid-rebind
install -m 0644 90-hid-rebind.rules /lib/udev/rules.d/90-hid-rebind.rules
udevadm control --reload
```

I would really love not to manually configure my kernel, but I'm open to it. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with one of the huion tablets on ubuntu 16.04. **You can not use the digimend-dkms_6_all.deb package**. Be sure to `sudo dpkg --purge digimend-dkms` it so that there isn't a trace.

You are doing the right thing by getting the drivers from https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers

The ssl errors have no bearing on the package installing. If you have tried installing this before I would run `sudo make uninstall` in the directory. Download the newest `digimend-kernel-drivers-master.zip` from the above site.

```
make
sudo make install
```

Here is where I had problems, says they are installed but it doesn't work. Run these commands now:

```
sudo rmmod hid-uclogic
sudo insmod hid-uclogic.ko
```

That should load the correct driver. For more detailed setup information you can look at [HUION H610 Tablet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500141/huion-h610-tablet). The information there pertains to most of the Huion tablet line.

Comment: This works also for Huion 950P on Ubuntu 16.04. Use the tar.gz instead of deb file to install.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as the original poster with the same symptoms.

The solution for me was to use version 5 (NOT version 6) of the DIGImend drivers.

I tried all methods with version 6 (deb package, make install, etc). 
No success.
I uninstalled/rmmod/purged all version 6 drivers, modules, and packages.
Finally, I downloaded version 5 kernel drivers from DIGImend github and "sudo make install" those.
That instantly worked!

So tldr: use version 5 drivers, not version 6 drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Huion H690 on Ubuntu 16.04: the tablet showed up in the `lsusb` output, but `xinput list` did not show it.

[This bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1575957) points to a wrong kernel module being loaded. After I removed the Digimend drivers and manually loaded the kernel module (`sudo insmod /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-uclogic.ko`), the tablet showed up in the `xinput list` output and I could use the pen as a mouse, without even having to unplug the tablet).