# Mapping Buttons on Huion H420 graphics tablet

Tags: graphics, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 17.04, graphics-tablet

I got a Huion H420 graphics tablet and I need to remap the keys. There are three key, which are mapped as left click, middle click(presumably) and right click.

I need a way to remap these keys to any other key on the keyboard, as I want to use it for graphics design.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04, and the tablet shows up with ID 17 when I run `xinput list`.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me after reading from various places viz. [bunnyrules's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/854842/769877) and the links therein, and [this](http://digimend.github.io/support/howto/drivers/wacom/):

1. Install DIGImend drivers first from [here](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/releases). I used the `.deb` (v7) file and it worked fine. You might also want to remove `hid-huion` module if you have it installed. Check with `lsmod`. Also you might need `libusb` and wacom binaries and libraries.

I had the following installed on 16.04:

```
libwacom-bin/xenial-updates,now 0.22-1~ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libwacom-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.22-1~ubuntu16.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
libwacom2/xenial-updates,now 0.22-1~ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
switchboard-plug-gcc-wacom/xenial,now 0.2.0-0~77~ubuntu0.4.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:0.34.0-0ubuntu2~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

2. Configure tablet in X: `sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-huion.conf`.

Use this configuration:

```
# Huion tablets
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Huion class"
    MatchProduct "HUION"
    MatchIsTablet "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "wacom"
EndSection
```

3. Now logout and login.

`xsetwacom` should now detect the H420.

```
% xsetwacom --list
HUION H420 Pen stylus                   id: 10  type: STYLUS
HUION H420 Pad pad                      id: 11  type: PAD
```

4. Now you can remap buttons:

ex. if you want to set Button 1 to page up.

`xsetwacom --set 'HUION H420 Pad pad' Button 1 "key +pgup"`

The format is `+` for press `-` for release followed by X11 KeySyms. For the full list see `xsetwacom --list modifiers` and also `man xsetwacom` (see PARAMETERS section)

You can also change mappings of the pen stylus buttons :). Button 1 is the pen tip and 2 and 3 are the ones on the pen.

If you screwed up a mapping, you can reset it like this:

`xsetwacom --set 'HUION H420 Pen stylus' Button 1 "button +1"`